# Struggling with MultiIndex Slicing (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I am organizing my data folders into multiindex dataframes with a structure similar to this:

```
In: df
Out: 
Sweep  Time       Primary  Secondary     720nm     473nm  PMTShutter                                                      
Sweep1 0.00000 -87.429810  -4.882812  0.000610  0.000305    0.000000
       0.00005 -87.445068  -4.882812  0.000610  0.001221    0.000000
       0.00010 -87.451172  -4.272460  0.000000  0.000916    0.000000
           ...        ...       ...       ...         ...  
Sweep5 0.68655 -87.261963  -4.272461  0.000305  0.000916    0.000305
       0.68660 -87.258911  -4.272461  0.000305  0.000916    0.000305
       0.68665 -87.252808  -5.493164  0.000000  0.000916    0.000305
       0.68670 -87.261963  -4.272461  0.000305  0.000916    0.000305
```

I am getting nowhere reading through the documentation for Pandas to try and figure out how to slice parts of this based on the two indexes though.

For example, I figured df['Sweep1'] would return everything for Sweep1. It does not, though. However, df.loc['Sweep1'] works how I would expect it. Why is this the case?

I seem to be completely unable to index by the Time index. For example, a very typical part of our analysis is to average data points over a specific range of time, or to find a maximum or minimum over a specific period of time. How, then, do I slice out a region of data based on a specific period of the Time index (e.g. Time 0.0sec through 0.5sec).

I can achieve this if I know the exact number of data points in that range (i.e. range * sampling freq), but the point of setting the Time to one of the indexes was to get around having to do that.

Similarly, if I want to plot let's say Sweep1 Primary by Time - I can't seem to figure out how to use the Time index as my x-axis.

So, I guess my main question is: How would I slice out data points from the different columns based on both the Sweep number and a certain sub-region of Time. That at least will point me in the right direction I think.

Thanks

Comment: I do not know a whole lot about the data, application, or libraries in use; To me this sounds like something that a database engine like sqlite3 might be suitable for; Where you can use a Query Language syntax to get the datapoints you want, instead of working with python data type primatives that may not suite your data lookup needs or the application inherently.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

`df['Sweep1']` is the correct syntax to return a column called Sweep1. To slice an index (row), you would do `df.ix['Sweep1']`.

**Question 2:**

You'll need to create a boolean series before slicing through Time. I think the easiest way would be to use it as a column, like

```
Time = df.reset_index('Time').Time
boolean = Time[(Time >= 0) & (Time < 0.5)]
result =  df.loc[('Sweep1', boolean),:]
```

Comment: Should I just leave Time as a column then? In the original data files when I import them time is just the first column and I convert it into an index. This seems like it might be counterproductive though.

Comment: Leave it as a column. Don't create a MultiIndex unless you have a compelling reason to do so. I only do when I need to isolate categories from values I'll operate on.

Comment: Well I still need to create a multiindex in that the Sweeps are the second index. It's just that instead of having Time as an index it will keep the default "index" values (i.e. 0 through #rows-1)

Comment: `ix` is not encouraged. `loc` and `iloc` (for pure positional indexing) are prefered.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you columns `Primary` and `PMTShutter` in the range t1-t2 of index `Sweep1`. t1 and t2 are floats.

```
idx = pandas.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['Sweep1',t1:t2],['Primary', 'PMTShutter']]
```